# Extend a class from an adapter class

Tags: java, android, interface, android-recyclerview, adapter

In my application should be a lot of adapters similar to each other and I would like to know whether it is possible to make the interface or superclass to inherit from there and then, instead of writing 10 adapters, thanks !!

My adapter code

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    private List<News> newsList;
    private Context ctx;

    public NewsAdapter(List<News> newsList, Context ctx) {
        this.newsList = newsList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView newsTitle;
        TextView newsDescription;
        ImageView newsImage;
        TextView newsDate;

        NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvNews);
            newsTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_news);
            newsDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_news);
            newsDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_news);
            newsImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_news);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent,
                false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.newsTitle.setText(newsList.get(position).newsTitle);
        holder.newsDescription.setText(newsList.get(position).newsDescription);
        holder.newsDate.setText(newsList.get(position).newsDate);
        Glide.with(ctx).load(Constants.SITE + newsList.get(position).newsImage)
                .into(holder.newsImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

[All should reflect like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFfMk.jpg)

Comment: *should be a lot of adapters similar to each*, how similar?

Comment: @Blackbelt they have a similar kind of design (items).... i have added a pic, please see it )

Comment: you can use same adapter, same view holder and also same POJO class if you have multiple lists that look same or are similar. if there are minor differences, you can always have if else blocks to serve your need instead of creating new adapter for every list.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I thought about what you wrote, but if I have an items in VievHolder, what i should do ? write many ViewHolders? or maybe something else?

Comment: as i told, if there is difference of 3 to 4 items, use if else block to use only the ones those are needed.

Comment: if you are talking about content, then just create a new instance of adapter and pass the list with new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is possible to make the interface or superclass to inherit from
>   there and then, instead of writing 10 adapters

It is possible, but of course there must be something in common. For a start the dataset should be homogeneous. E.g. your items should all implement an interface, a contract between the item and the adapter itself. In your case, it could be

```
public interface DataItem {
     String getTitle();
     String getDescription();
     String getDate();
     String getImageUrl();
}
```

and instead of a `private List<News> newsList;`, you will have private `List<? extends DataItem> newsList;`. As I said, all your items have to implement that interface, and the properties have to be accessed through the getters